# \arraystrech does not work for tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I'm trying to remove a vertical blank in a table by `arraystrech` but it does not work for some reason. I want to adjust the height of the rows to save more space in my resume.

```latex
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{parskip}    
\usepackage{here}

\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength{\fullcollw}
\setlength{\fullcollw}{0.47\textwidth}
\usepackage{titlesec}               
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\usepackage[sorting=none, maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[unicode, draft=false]{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1em}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Job Experience}
{\newcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}l r@{} }
    \textbf{Row 1 (position name) } & \hfill  Date1 \\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}X@{}}{
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.7cm]
                \item Some explanations of the position.... It is long and occupies the two columns... 
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \\
    \textbf{Row 2 (position name) } & \hfill Date2 \\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}X@{}}{
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.7cm]
                \item Some explanations of the position.... It is long and occupies the two columns...
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \\ 
    \textbf{Row 3 (position name) }  & \hfill Date3\\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}X@{}}{
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.7cm]
                \item Some explanations of the position.... It is long and occupies the two columns...
            \end{itemize}
        }
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you expect `\newcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}` to do??? This is unrelated to `tabularx` it specfies table rows should use normal size text on lines which are spaced just a tenth of the normal space. That can not work. it also needs `\re` `newcommand` do not ignore errors: `! LaTeX Error: Command \arraystretch already defined.`

Comment: also `tabularx` requires an `X` column `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}l r@{} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \arraystretch already defined
```

as redefining `\arraystretch` requires `\renewcommand`

But a value of 0.1 can do nothing useful, it specifies the lines of a table should be closer together than the height of the letters.

In general `tabularx` requires an `X` column so

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}l r@{} }
```

is wrong, you could use `lX` but there is no alignment required here so I would remove the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{parskip}    
\usepackage{here}

\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength{\fullcollw}
\setlength{\fullcollw}{0.47\textwidth}
\usepackage{titlesec}               
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\usepackage[sorting=none, maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[unicode, draft=false]{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1em}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Job Experience}

\noindent\textbf{Row 1 (position name)}\hfill  Date1
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.7cm]
                \item Some explanations of the position.... It is long and occupies the two columns... 
            \end{itemize}
        
\noindent\textbf{Row 2 (position name)\hfill Date2
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.7cm]
                \item Some explanations of the position.... It is long and occupies the two columns...
            \end{itemize}

\noindent\textbf{Row 3 (position name)\hfill Date3
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.7cm]
                \item Some explanations of the position.... It is long and occupies the two columns...
            \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sir! I have misunderstood the use of `\arraystretch`. Is it possible to make the vertical spacings between the lines smaller?

Comment: @Ogiad the space comes from the list so use the `enumitem` keys to control space just as you are using them for the margin.